# My WPBakery page layouts are no longer working on my Wordpress Site, using Stockholm Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wpbakery

I am no longer able to see the editing facility on my wordpress portfolio posts, and the live site has altered layouts on almost all pages. I am running the Stockholm theme (v.9.6.1) and WPBakery Page Builder (v.7.3) - they are both up to date.

Example:

https://americansupplyparis.com/portfolio_page/air-noodles/

Normally this page has a portfolio slider on the header, and several columns. The slider has been removed and all columns are compacted to the left side vertically.

I have tried deactivating all other plugins, and the only one that seems to do anything is deactivating the WPBakery Page Builder plugin, but then the layout all needs to be reformatted across the site, and the issue affects around 150 portfolio items.

Is there a way to identify the problem and have any of you had any problems with integration in the new Stockholm theme with WPBakery Page Builder?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing if you've updated WordPress, the Stockholm theme or WPBakery Page Builder prior to the issues with your site, it's hard to say. But the first thing you should do is open the pages in question on your site in your web browser, then open your Developer Tools and reload the page while viewing the Console and Network tabs.

It's important to learn to use your browser's developer tools and should be among the first things you do when troubleshooting any site. Here are three resources that will help you (and others) out with that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/visual-studio-code/microsoft-edge-devtools-extension/open-devtools-and-embedded-browser

You've got quite a few errors showing when I attempted to load the example URL you included in your questions. I'm enclosing a screenshot.

[image]

Here's a few trouble-shooting steps you can take.

### First, Can You Restore To A Previously Working Version?

If your site previously worked and you updated WP, your theme or the builder, can you restore the previous versions, through a snapshot/backup? If so, do that and see if your site works. If you can't, it isn't practical, or you don't have an additional test environment duplicating your deployment environment, then you will need to move forward fixing errors. At some point, they're either all fixed and the site works, or you realize there's an error in something and have to either (A) wait for an update from the offending component, (B) find another solution, (C) manually restore your site to a previously working condition.

### Next, Fix Mixed Content Errors

You have mixed content errors--files are being requested with 'http' urls being served over an 'https' connection. The first thing to do is go through and ensure all resources are being requested as 'https' in your theme/templates. Use 'search and replace' feature of your code editor or a utility to go through the theme. Make sure your settings in WP are set to server everything over 'https'. You may need to go through your database manually or with a search and replace utility, searching for 'http' and ensure ever result returned has the 's' added to become 'https'. Back up your database first if you have to do that.

Here's a few links on performing a database search and replace in WordPress.

https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-perform-search-and-replace-in-wordpress-database/

https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-find-and-replace-text-with-one-click-in-your-wordpress-database/

And a utility to use if you need:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

### Next, Ensure Requested Resources Are Present

This means checking in your theme and uploads that the actual files your theme/templates are requesting exist. There are several resources requested related to your JS-Composer plugin that are returning 404 errors (not found).

### Make Sure Scripts Are Correctly Coded

There are several JS issues related to 'flexslider' not being a function.

```
jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $j(...).flexslider is not a function TypeError: $j(...).flexslider is not a function
```

So, you need to check your JavaScript, resources, and make sure everything is being served over https. It's always possible a recent update to a theme or builder pushed a breaking change (like not including an updated script), left out a resource or something.

### Steps You Can Take In The Future

Make sure you have backups/snapshots so that you can easily and quickly restore a WordPress install to a working condition. If your current host doesn't have some mechanism to create backups, you can use a plugin. One I've used for myself and clients, and have recommended for years, is:

https://servmask.com/products

Many hosts allow you to take snapshots/backups, so make use of them. Take a snapshot before you update any plugins, WordPress, themes or builders. Then, if your host allows multiple snapshots or backups, take another after a successful update. You always want to have a good backup or snapshot of a known working version before you upgrade, so you don't have to deal with broken sites being public facing for more than a very short while. If your current host/platform doesn't have backup/snapshot capability, consider finding a new one. It's common, saves headaches and time, provides peace of mind.

- Use your Dev Tools for troubleshooting.
- Be sure to test. A second server/environment is important to use, whether a local dev environment or another VPS or container.
- Disable automatic updates for WordPress, plugins, themes, etc., do them manually.